# solving $y=4/x+\sqrt{x+0.2−5x}$

Tags: quadratics

it's actually

$y=\frac{4}{x}+\sqrt{x+0.2-5x}$ (see [algebra problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjjJT.jpg))

$$y=\frac{4}{x}+\sqrt{x+0.2-5x}$$
if $x=\frac45$
what is y?

Comment: If $x$ is a constant, either write it down, or use a calculator

Answer (score 2):

Since $\frac{4}{5} = 0.8$,
$$ y = \frac{4}{x} + \sqrt{x + 0.2} - 5x = \frac{4}{4/5} + \sqrt{0.8+0.2} - 5 \cdot \frac{4}{5} = 5 + \sqrt{1} - 4 = 2
$$

Edit: Since you've modified the question,
$$ y = \frac{4}{x} + \sqrt{x + 0.2 - 5x} = \frac{4}{4/5} + \sqrt{0.8 + 0.2 - 4} = 5 \pm \sqrt{3}i
$$

Comment: Actually it's not $\sqrt{x+\frac{2}{10}} - 5x$ but $\sqrt{x+\frac{2}{10} - 5x}$ (but when you answered the question's formatting was misleading)

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \frac{4}{x} + \sqrt{x+.2-5x}$

$f(4/5) = \frac{4}{4/5}+ \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}+0.2-5(\frac{4}{5})} = 5 + \sqrt{3}i$

Comment: ok can you guys please help with this one?

Comment: This is the wrong forum to get people to just do your homework.

Comment: but im so hopeless at maths & you guys are so good! & doesnt it feel good to help someone in need?

Comment: @user329008 Here's a website you can use to solve your math problems: http://www.wolframalpha.com/